# How to append dynamic DOM elements from a pipe in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I m trying to append a mat-spinner from a pipe directive that should add the loading when the | async is executing

I have this guy for transform

```
transform(val: any): any {
this.showLoader();
return isObservable(val)
  ? val.pipe(
      catchError((error) => of(this.hideLoader())),
      finalize(() => this.hideLoader())
    )
  : val;
```

}

and this for show loader:

```
  showLoader(): void {
   const componentFactory = 
   this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory<MatSpinner(MatSpinner);
   const matSpinner = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

   matSpinner.instance.diameter = 24;

   this.progressElement = matSpinner.injector.get(MatSpinner)._elementRef.nativeElement;
   this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, this.progressElement);
```

}

Unfortunately when I m trying to append the child I get this error
[image]

Any suggestions how to overcome this? Or any other idea will be helpfull.

ps: the final product should be something like this `<div *ngIf="data$ | loadingPipe | async> </div>`

Comment: Is this animation full screen?

Comment: nope, it should be in the element from where I added the pipe